# Instant Search for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, search

Are there any 'instant search' modules (similar to Google's instant search) available for Drupal 7?

I found the Drupal 6 modules listed below, but neither of them seems to be available for Drupal 7, yet.

- [Drupal Instant search](http://drupal.org/project/instant)
- [Instant Search](http://drupal.org/project/instant_search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) module; I haven't used the D7 version yet, but the Drupal 6 version worked well for my needs.